# Twig: Include external Code from an SVG file

Tags: svg, twig, inline, templating

Is it possible to inlcude code from a svg file directly into a twig template file?

Something like:

```
{% include 'my.svg' %}
```

that will result in:

```
<svg viewbox=".... />
```

Comment: If you place that file in your template folder, sure

Answer (score 20):

One way of doing this:

```
{{ source('my.svg') }}
```

Read more here:
https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2017/01/integrating-and-interacting-with-svg-image-files-using-twig/

Answer (score 12):

In case of theme it's good option to use `{{ directory }}` variable that holds path to theme.

```
{{ source(directory ~ '/images/my.svg') }}
```

Answer (score 10):

Had a similar issue, ended up renaming my svgs to be .twig files.

`{% include 'my.svg.twig' %}`

Answer (score 3):

For me, it worked:

```
{% include '/images/my.svg' %}
```

Just a quick update if you are using Drupal 8 because the code in the previous answer didn't work for me. This is how I did it:

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $svg = file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name') . '/images/my.svg');
  $variables['some_svg'] = $svg;
}
```

And in the twig file, output using `raw` filter, or else it will escape the SVG markup:

```
{{ some_svg|raw }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The twig function source() works fine in Drupal.  I am not sure if it's better to use source() or include, but the Symfony docs recommend using the include() function rather than the directive.  https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html

I also find it helps to add the theme namespace, which tells Twig to look in the templates directory.

Assuming:

- template file is themes/custom/theme_name/templates/some-template.html.twig
- svg file is themes/custom/theme_name/templates/svg/sprite.svg

```
  {{ source('@theme_name/svg/sprite.svg') }}
{# or #}
  {% include '@theme_name/svg/sprite.html.twig' %}
{# or #}
  {{ include('@theme_name/svg/sprite.html.twig') }}
```

This should also work for module templates as well as theme templates.

I would think there is a performance benefit to using source() since the contents aren't parsed, but if you wanted a dynamic SVG, you should probably go the include() route.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a Drupal8 theme via setting a new variable:

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $svg = file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('theme', 'socialbase') . '/images/icons.svg');
  $variables['svg_sprite'] = t('svg', array('svg' => $svg));
}
```

In your twig file you can print it with:

```
{{ svg_sprite }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Drupal 9:

```
{% include active_theme_path() ~ '/images/sprite.svg' %}
```